# Strongly typed links in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 beta

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, strong-typing

With ASP.NET MVC 1.0 I always have been able to generate strongly typed links in my Views using a lambda function:

```
Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<TController>(c => c.Action(arg));
```

I'm now upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 2.0 beta and I can't find **any** strongly typed extension for the HtmlHelper (nor the UrlHelper in fact). Have they been replaced by some other method? Is there a new way of building links to controller actions?

I'd hate to go back to using strings in my views.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It takes one line to implement you own extension with same functionality. I actually do it even in MVC v1, because Url.Href<> is shorter ;-) You can copy code from MVC sources for this.

Comment: Ok, I was just checking for some new "official" way of building links I was unaware of. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The strongly-typed URL generation helpers are part of the MVC Futures binary, not the MVC core binary itself.  You can download a version of MVC Futures that works with MVC 2 Beta [from CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=36054).